# Use layout_weight in a Linear Layout Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to use layout_weight in a Linear Layout but it is not setting up proper layout .It's all getting mixed up .proper gap in not there in each textview .Please help me to fix this .

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainResultLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/request_date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="25 Sep 2013 | 09:45" 
        android:layout_gravity="left"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/approval_id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="XXXXXXXX"
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trip_date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="25 Sep 2013"
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trip_id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="XXXXXXXXXX"
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/approval_status"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Waiting"
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So please help to fix this issue will be thank full to you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainResultLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/request_date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="25 Sep 2013 | 09:45" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/approval_id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="XXXXXXXX" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trip_date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="25 Sep 2013" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trip_id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="XXXXXXXXXX" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/approval_status"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Waiting" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code to set proper gap in each layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainResultLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/request_date"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".20"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="25 Sep 2013 | 09:45" 
    android:layout_gravity="left"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/approval_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".20"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="XXXXXXXX"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/trip_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".20"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="25 Sep 2013"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/trip_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".20"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="XXXXXXXXXX"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/approval_status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".20"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Waiting"
    />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with  android:layout_width="match_perent" in each textview properties

Answer (score 0):

Change *android:layout_width="0dp"* with *android:layout_height="wrap_content"* or *android:layout_height="wrap_content"*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/request_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="25 Sep 2013 | 09:45" 
    android:layout_gravity="left"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/approval_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="XXXXXXXX"
    android:layout_gravity="right" 
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/trip_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="25 Sep 2013"
    android:layout_gravity="right" 
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/trip_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="XXXXXXXXXX"
    android:layout_gravity="right" 
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/approval_status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Waiting"
    android:layout_gravity="right" 
    />
```

Also, if you don't have to add anything else, you can use only one **LinearLayout**.

Answer (score 0):

What is the second linear layout doing in the xml?.you want to have all these text views aligned in a line with equal weight?remove the android:layout_gravity="left" from all your text views. Do it like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainResultLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/request_date"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="25 Sep 2013 | 09:45" 
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/approval_id"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="XXXXXXXX"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/trip_date"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="25 Sep 2013"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/trip_id"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="XXXXXXXXXX"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/approval_status"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Waiting"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the width to match_parent in each case.

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/request_date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="25 Sep 2013 | 09:45" 
    android:layout_gravity="left"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/approval_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="XXXXXXXX"
    android:layout_gravity="right" 
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/trip_date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="25 Sep 2013"
    android:layout_gravity="right" 
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/trip_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="XXXXXXXXXX"
    android:layout_gravity="right" 
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/approval_status"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Waiting"
    android:layout_gravity="right" 
    />
```